# Ruby splat operator changing value inside loop

Tags: ruby, splat

I want to define a method which can take an optional amount of arguments and hashes, like so

```
def foo(*b, **c)
  2.times.map.with_index { |i|
    new_hash, new_array = {}, b
    c.map { |key, value| new_hash[key] = value[i] unless value[i].nil? }
    new_array << new_hash if new_hash.length > 0
    send(:bar, new_array)
  }
end

def bar(*b)
  p b
end
```

If I've understood the splat and double splat operators correctly (which I doubt), then this should send the array `b` to the `bar` method, and only adding the `new_hash` from `foo` if it contains something. However, something weird happens - I'll try and illustrate with some snippets below

```
# invoking #foo 
foo(a, key: 'value')

# first iteration of loop in #foo
  # i is 0
  # b is []
  # c is { :key => ['value1'] }
  # send(:bar, new_array) => send(:bar, [{:key => 'value1'}])
  # bar yields: [{:key => 'value1'}]
```

Now, however, something happens

```
# second iteration of loop in #foo
  # i is 1
  # b is [:key => 'value1'] <---- why?
  # c is { :key => ['value1']
```

Why has the value of `b` changed inside the loop of `foo`?

**edit** Updated the code to reflect a new array is created for each iteration

Comment: Your code doesn't match up with your example at all.

Comment: Gah! And you just edited it to remove the error you're asking about!

Comment: Dude, I'm trying to clarify my point because I was apparently very tired when I asked the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
new_hash, new_array = {}, b
```

This doesn't create a copy of `b`. Now `new_array` and `b` point to the *same object*. Modifying one in-place will modify the other.

```
new_array << new_hash
```

That modifies `new_array` (and thus `b`) in place, so the new element remains on the next iteration. Use something like `+`, which creates a copy:

```
send(:bar, *(b + (new_hash.empty? ? [] : [new_hash])))
```

Comment: Yeah, sorry about the first code I submitted, I think I was tired when I wrote that :p. Anyway, the `send` statement doesn't use a hardcoded symbol in the code base, it's just for illustrative purposes that I've used the `:bar` symbol. It's the same with map with index (which is used in the code body btw).

Comment: Gotcha. Consider creating a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) the next time you ask a question on Stack Overflow. 1) leaving out unnecessary details will make it easier for people to understand your problem, 2) it may help _you_ figure out your problem before you even ask about it!

Comment: Ah, that's a good suggestion. I think I just realised my mistake also, because the parameters I'm operating on are within a yielded block.